# Verpflichtungserklärung for Non-EU Parents Visiting Germany - Do I Need One or Two Documents?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, invitation-letters

Hello fellow travelers,

I am currently in the process of planning a visit for my non-EU parents to Berlin, Germany, and I have a question regarding the Verpflichtungserklärung (formal obligation letter) requirement. I hope someone here can provide some insight or share their personal experience.

My parents are residents of an Asian country and do not hold citizenship in any EU country. They plan to stay with me in Berlin for a short-term visit, not exceeding 90 days. I know they need a Verpflichtungserklärung to apply for a Schengen visa.

My question is: Do I need to provide one Verpflichtungserklärung document or two separate documents for both of my parents? I want to ensure I have all the necessary documentation to avoid complications during their visa application process.

I have researched the topic, but the information I found seems to be a bit unclear or inconsistent. Some sources mention the need for a separate document for each visitor, while others suggest that one document may be sufficient for a family unit.

If anyone has any firsthand experience or knowledge regarding this matter, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Additionally, providing any relevant information about the application process or any specific requirements in Berlin would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance for your assistance, and I look forward to hearing from you!

Comment: You may or may not need the *Verpflichtungserklärung.* It is required if the visitors would otherwise have problems to meet the conditions for the visa. Basically you promise to reimburse the state for any costs of overstay and you put up a bond for some of that amount, so the visa officials are less worried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to provide one Verpflichtungserklärung document or two separate documents for both of my parents?

You need only one Verpflichtungserklärung and one appointment.

The form is built for **one visitor** with extra fields for:

- accompanied by his or her spouse [of the visitor]
- accompanied by children [of the visitor]
- relationship of the applicant to the visitor

> while others suggest that one document may be sufficient for a family unit.

Yes, the family unit **of the visitor** (the visitors spouse or children).

Since your second parent is the spouse of your first parent (that you, as applicant, enter into the form), that parent is added in a special field if the second parent is accompaning the first. The same is true  for any children of the first parent.

---

> **Documents required**
>
> - Form „Angaben zur Verpflichtungserklärung“ (filled out)
>   ...
>
>   - **Accompanying spouses** and minor unmarried children **of your visitor** can be entered on the same form.
>   - For each other family member accompanying your visitor, please fill in a separate declaration of commitment.
>     ...

---

- [Declaration of commitment for a short-term stay (Schengen visa) - Services - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/120691/en/)